# How to upload folder of images using pinata - ipfs?

Tags: javascript, nft, ipfs, pinata

How to upload a folder of images, by giving only path using npm's pinata sdk ? I only want to give folder's path. using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After a lot of R&D,found out that you cannot, upload folder of images using the pinata sdk(npm pack.). But you can use Moralis and IPFS public gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const IMAGES_LOCATION = "path/to/folder";
const imageFolderUploadResponse = await pinata.pinFromFS(IMAGES_LOCATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple using node.js (Javascript)

1. First resolve the dir path
2. Read by fs module in node.js
3. Put the stuff in loop as per below code and then it will automatically pin your files to the Pinat

```js
async function storeImages(imagesDirPath) {
  const fullImagesPath = path.resolve(imagesDirPath);
  const files = fs.readdirSync(fullImagesPath);
  let responses = [];
  console.log("Uploading to Pinata !!!");
  console.log("paths ", fs.createReadStream(fullImagesPath + "/" + files[0]));
  for (fileIndex in files) {
    const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(
      `${fullImagesPath}/${files[fileIndex]}`
    );
    try {
      const response = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile);
      responses.push(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return { responses, files };
}
```